# click trigger not working on disabled button after enabling

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

while making a chrome extension, i am trying to simulate a click event on the buttons of a web page. the function simulateClick() is working fine for all the buttons except one which is disabled. this disabled button gets enabled when something is typed in the preceding text-area. i changed the value of textarea, still the button did not get enabled. so i tried enabling it myself, by removing the attribute "disabled" from that button. still no luck.

```
let msgNote = document.querySelector(inputBox);
msgNote.value = "new value";
let doneBtn = document.querySelector("disabled-done-btn");
doneBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
simulateClick(doneBtn);
```

```
function simulateClick(onElement) {
  let mouseClick = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  mouseClick.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  let cb = onElement;
  let canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(mouseClick);
}
```

Comment: Check in devtools "event listeners" panel the actual events used by the button or its ancestors, they could be different e.g. 'mousedown'.

Comment: how to check for that button?

Comment: got it, thank you!

Comment: @wOxxOm that's not the case. is there any way to enable the button and change the value of the text input simultaneously!

Comment: Try [Chrome extension: enter data into a custom-handled input field](//stackoverflow.com/a/57900849)

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the answer, it works completely fine now. please turn your comment into answer!

Answer (score 0):

$('#textarea').click(function() { //Here button disable true or false });

document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;

document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false;

$('#Button').attr('disabled','disabled');

$('#Button').removeAttr('disabled');

$('#Button').prop('disabled', true);

$('#Button').prop('disabled', false);

Comment: i didn't get you :/